# Do you like puzzles?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

I hope this isn't too easy, nor too hard; this is my first enigmatic puzzle! Good luck to you all, and have fun!

---

> I like puzzles.
>
> What
>
> Do you like puzzles
>
> Yes
>
> That is why you came
>
> Well I have a puzzle just for you today
>
> Solve it
>
> It is not all that hard
>
> I implore you to read
>
> This puzzle barge

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Is it simply:

> $\pi$?

My reasoning:

> Each of the lines contains a specific number of words that represent the value of $\pi$ to $9$ decimal places.

The first line; *I like puzzles.*

> Represents the 3 and the decimal point as it is three words and the only line with punctuation.

The rest of the lines:

> Represent the decimal places under the same criteria: 141592653.

Hence the answer must be:

> $\pi$ or $3.141592653$

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Could you break down your answer for us so we get a better idea of your reasoning? +1 From me!

Comment: I guess that's the answer. What a cool puzzle haha!